# Should I use Full Join in this multi-database SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a query supposedly with a output like this:

[image]

And here is my query:

```
select 
    table4.categoryNames, -- because only table4 has all the categories
    table1.countResult, -- either (DATA) or null
    table2.countResult,
    table3.countResult,
    table4.countResult,
    table5.countResult,
    table6.countResult,
    table7.countResult
from 
    table1 
full join 
    table2 on table1.categoryNames = table2.CategoryNames
full join 
    table3 on table2.categoryNames = table3.CategoryNames
full join 
    table4 on table3.categoryNames = table4.CategoryNames
full join 
    table5 on table4.categoryNames = table5.CategoryNames
full join 
    table6 on table5.categoryNames = table6.CategoryNames
full join 
    table7 on table6.categoryNames = table7.CategoryNames
```

and each `countResult` is a query itself counting IDs grouped by the field `CategoryNames` of table `someTable` in its respective database:

```
with table1 as 
(
    select 
        categroyName, count(ID) as countResult
    from 
        database1.someTable
    group by 
        categroyName),
-- table2 from database2.someTable
-- table3 from database3.someTable , and so on
```

I wish there is a `category` table, but there is none. The output is not correct, because it shows a 7th category with the name `NULL`.

I am new to SQL and I just want to know what is the best `join` I should use in this case.

Comment: You need a 'master category' table which from your SQL comments would appear to be `SELECT DISTINCT categoryNames FROM table4`. Now you just need to left join everything to that master subtable. By subtable I mean something defined like this: `(SELECT DISTINCT categoryNames FROM table4) MySubtable` you can refer to this table as `MySubTable` in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `union all` and `group by` might be a better approach.  Here is the basic idea:

```
select categoryName,
       max(cr1), max(cr2), max(cr3), max(cr4), max(cr5), max(cr6), max(cr7)
from ((select categoryName, countResults as cr1, NULL as cr2, NULL as cr3,
              NULL as cr4, NULL as cr5, NULL as cr6, NULL as cr7
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select categoryName, NULL as cr1, countResults as cr2, NULL as cr3,
              NULL as cr4, NULL as cr5, NULL as cr6, NULL as cr7
       from table2
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) t
group by categoryName;
```

If you have all the categories in a table, then another approach is to use `left join`:

```
select c.categoryname, t1.countResult, t2.countResult, . . .
from categories c left join
     table1 t1
     on c.categoryname = t1.categoryname left join
     table2 t2
     on c.categoryname = t2.categoryname left join
     . . . ;
```

Comment: creating a `categories` table and then `left join ` seems to be a simpler solution. Thank you very much